# How can I instantiate game objects in Unity (C#) along with an instantiated integer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm trying to have health points to the instantiated enemies of my game.
At first the enemies were just destroyed as soon as a single shot hit them.

I thought adding a new class just holding the HP of the instantiated prefab would work, but I don't know how to write that correctly. Either it's "static" and then I know how to call it from the bullet controller class, but it's not instantiated and the same int value is kept for all instantiated enemies, or it is not "static" and then I don't know how to call it from the other classes.

Here is the code currently, for the bullet controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform bullet;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bullet = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bullet.position += transform.up * speed;
        if (bullet.position.y >= 10)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Enemy4HP.health--;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            if (Enemy4HP.health < 1)
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                PlayerScore.playerScore++;
            }
        }
        if (other.tag == "Enemy2")
        {
            Enemy10HP.health--;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            if (Enemy10HP.health <1)
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                PlayerScore.playerScore++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and for the two health classes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy4HP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 4;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy10HP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 10;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is how the enemies get instantiated:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform enemyHolder;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject shot;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject enemy2;
    public Text winText;
    int secCount;
    float timer = 0;
    public float fireRate = 0.997f;
    public int enemyCount;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemyCount = 0;
        secCount = 0;
        enemyHolder = GetComponent<Transform>();
        winText.enabled = false;
        InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemy", 0f, 0.016f);
    }
    private List<GameObject> allSpawns = new List<GameObject>();

    void MoveEnemy()
    {
        float xPosition = Random.Range(-11f, 11f);
        int enemyType = Random.Range(0, 8);
        secCount = Random.Range(2, 4);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= secCount && enemyCount < 25)
        {
            if (enemyType > 0)
            {
                GameObject spawned = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(xPosition, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                allSpawns.Add(spawned);
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject spawned = Instantiate(enemy2, new Vector3(xPosition, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                allSpawns.Add(spawned);
            }
            enemyCount++;
            timer = timer - secCount;
        }
        foreach (GameObject thisEnemy in allSpawns)
        {
            if (thisEnemy !=null)
            {
                thisEnemy.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1 * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }
        if (PlayerScore.playerScore == 25)
        {
            timer = 0;
            CancelInvoke();
            InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemy2", 0f, 0.016f);
        }
    }
 ...
```

That returns "An object reference is required for the non_static field...". What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest checking out a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAM6fE3Cnk8) showing how to use Raycasts to calculate hits rather than the projectile itself. It's a better approach (not seen that tutorial, was just the 1st in search results )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest quickest. Instead of 2 classes with 2 different number make 1 called EnemyHP. Add the component to the enemy prefabs and on the prefab in the inspector set the component's health to 4 for enemy 1 and 10 for enemy 2. Then :

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    //you can probably just make both enemy the same tag.
    if (other.tag == "Enemy" || other.tag == "Enemy2")
    {
        //get the Hp component of the specific enemy.
        EnemyHP hpComponent = other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHP>();
        hpComponent.health--;
        Destroy(gameObject);
        if (hpComponent.health < 1)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            PlayerScore.playerScore++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I'm trying to test it but now for some reason Unity doesn't allow me to add newly created scripts to the objects. It keeps saying "Can't add script behavior AssemblyInfo.cs. The script needs to derive from MonoBehavior". I'm using Visual Studio, and the answers I found for this didn't help.

Comment: Is you EnemyHP class derived from mono? public class EnemyHP : MonoBehaviour. If not you wont be able to add it as a component. Also right after you create a new script unity will recompile (you see a loading icon near the bottom right of the editor). If its still compiling while trying to add the new script it might fail.

Comment: It is, like all scripts created from within Unity. It didn't let me attach new scripts at first, and after restarting Unity (which made it load for much longer than usual) it now doesn't even allow me to attach the older scripts! I don't understand this bug. EDIT: Making a new project doesn't show this problem, so I think it corrupted my game's project somehow! What should I do?

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? You ned to fix any compiling issues if there are any.

Comment: I don't try to run the game and it doesn't currently show any compiling issues. I said, the script files should be as they were previously, but Unity doesn't make the drag&drop action work now for whatever reason.

Comment: Ok, after looking through the code I found one of the scripts had errors it didn't notify about until entering the piece of code again. I removed that part, re-saved all and now it allows dropping the code onto objects. But I'm sorry if it sounds stupid – I didn't understand how implement your code. Nothing works in the ways I'm trying to write it. How do you phrase the components part inside the EnemyHP class?

Comment: 1-Create the EnemyHP script. Its the same has your Enemy10HP script.
2-You have Enemy and Enemy2 prefabs (or gameobjects in your scene). The ones linked in your enemycontroller class. On each of them add the EnemyHP script as a component.
3-On the same prefabs/GameObject you just added the script, change the value of health to what your looking for (4 for enemy & 10 for enemy2)
4-Replace the OntriggerEnter2D function from your bulletcontroller script with the code snippet i written.
Should work.

Comment: Hm... But it keeps giving error "Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'EnemyHP'. Did you intend to invoke the method?".

Comment: Can you show your code where the error occurs. Seems like your missing parenthesis ()

Comment: You're right! Thanks. I've actually looked elsewhere about this error message and someone was suggested about the parenthesis, but I looked at your code again rather than checking what I wrote and saw you did use parenthesis so I thought it is something else. But I just missed that bit in your answer.